# How can I compute pseudo determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let A square n by n matrix
 and let b:=pseudo det of A
And assume that A is diagonalizable  and rkA=r
Then what is pseudo det of AA^(t)??

Comment: Have you tried computing in the case $A$ is a diagonal matrix?

Comment: Yes.. but I don't know how to generalize